# Replacing values in Rust causing "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to build a graphics engine that works with the fairly common two-buffer pattern. One buffer (`current_buffer`) is displayed while the next (`next_buffer`) is prepared, then the next buffer is moved into the current buffer, and is subsequently repopulated by a new buffer, repeating.

I know there are ***a lot*** of other questions about `cannot move out of borrowed content` errors, so I spent a while looking at all I can find so far before finally resorting to asking this as a question.

Here's my code:

```
pub fn update(&mut self, dt: f64) {
    if self.is_change_buffer {
        self.current_buffer = self.next_buffer;
        self.next_buffer = Buffer { ... }; // New buffer
    }
}
```

I'm running into problems with moving `self.next_buffer` to `self.current_buffer`, which is understandable considering that `self.current_buffer = self.next_buffer` would break the "one owner" principle. **How do I tell the borrow checker that I'm not trying to alias `self.next_buffer`, I'm trying to move it, and put something new in its place?**

A caveat due to a framework I'm working with is that the function signature of `update()` *must be*:

```
pub fn (&mut self, dt: f64) -> ()
```

Also, a `Buffer` *cannot* be cloned. Because of the way `Buffer`s are stored, cloning them would be an extremely expensive operation, and so cannot practically be done at every screen refresh.

Comment: Why don't you have two concrete buffers and just swap a reference to them? [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3a49b3d69d3ba612caaef67ce3a27f07)

Answer (score 4):

> How do I tell the borrow checker that I'm not trying to alias `self.next_buffer`, I'm trying to move it, and put something new in its place?

The borrow checker is not complaining about aliasing – it is complaining because you are moving a field out of a struct that you only borrowed, which is not allowed.  However, moving out and immediately replacing with a new value *is* allowed, and there is a dedicated function for exactly this use case, called [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/std/mem/fn.replace.html).  With this function, your code becomes

```
self.current_buffer = mem::replace(&mut self.next_buffer, Buffer { ... });
```

Comment: Indeed your solution produces slightly shorter code than mine, so it will be a bit faster [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=bd47aad8cb3e07dee8f4aa2bdaf2b3db).

Comment: @rodrigo Yours assigns `self.next_buffer` twice – the first time in the `swap()` call, but it is immediately overwritten with the new buffer.  This isn't really buffer swapping, since a new buffer is created.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution is to use [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html):

```
std::mem::swap(&mut self.next_buffer, &mut self.current_buffer);
self.next_buffer = Buffer { ... }; // New buffer
```

You can also assign first and then swap, but I find it more natural this way.

Comment: I think `mem::replace()` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: That works, but I like the ring of `swap` because this operation in double-buffer is usually called _swapping_ and sometimes the old buffer gets reused. With your suggestion it would look like `let next = std::mem::replace(&mut self.next_buffer, new Buffer { ... }); self.current_buffer = next;`, which looks nice too, if you don't plan to reuse the old buffer.

Comment: I'll just add this as a separate answer. :)